# why it is called 'APPROLE_Admin' instead of 'Admin' in Spring boot App secured by Azure AD

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory

I followed the article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory and created an App role

[image]

and assigned the user

[image]

in the spring boot application, I have to use 'APPROLE_Admin' instead of 'Admin' ? why? it is supposed to be only 'Admin', correct?

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TutorialController {

    @Autowired
    TutorialRepository tutorialRepository;

    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('APPROLE_Admin')")
    @GetMapping("/tutorials")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `APPROLE_` prefix is coming from a default property configuration from Spring Cloud Azure.

```
spring.cloud.azure.active-directory.resource-server.claim-to-authority-prefix-map
```

> Configure which claim will be used to build GrantedAuthority, and prefix of the GrantedAuthority’s string value. Default value is: "scp" → "SCOPE_", "roles" → "APPROLE_".

[Documentation link](https://microsoft.github.io/spring-cloud-azure/docs/4.0.0-beta.1/reference/html/index.html#configuration-6)

You can update the property with a desired prefix:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      active-directory:
        resource-server:
          claim-to-authority-prefix-map:
            roles: "" # no prefix
            scp: "MY_SCP_PREFIX_"
```